# is stack doing something funny in my python program

Tags: python, recursion, stack

I have this program where the function has a for loop as below where I am calling the same function recursively.

```
class soln(object):
  def test(self, start, end):
    for i in range (start, end):
      print ("here1 i %d" % i)
      if (i==2):
        return 6
      i = self.test(i+1, end)
      print(i)
      

my = soln()
my.test(0,4)


output is 
here1 i 0
here1 i 1
here1 i 2
6
here1 i 2

I expected to see i to be 6 not 2
```

Even though I am changing the values of the iterator after returning from the recursive call, the iterator goes back to its old value. The stack would have returned back to the previous stack where the iterator i should have the new value. Maybe I am a little dumb to understand this and appreciate some info as well as how do I change i to the returned value from the recursive call?

Comment: It's not good practice to change the loop value inside the for-loop - and as you noticed, it's hard to predict which value it'll get

Comment: @stefan we can have logic (assume there is no recursion but some other logic), and depending on that i can change i isnt it? for ex:  in ```after the return call instead of recursion, I can do i += 4 ```. Then i will change isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

You are printing before returning.  try this:

```
class soln(object):
    def test(self, start, end):
        for i in range(start, end):
            if i == 2:
                return 6
            print("here i %d" % i)
            i = self.test(i + 1, end)
            print("here i is", i)


my = soln()
my.test(0, 4)
```

Comment: That doesnt work either as the iterator i changes its value back to earlier one the moment we hit for loop (after returning from the previous recursion)and move to if condition

Answer (score 0):

I changed the for loop to this

```
while (start < end):
...
start +=1
```

Seems to be working for few test cases. But will check more tests.